# ShowModal form behind Showmodal form Delphi Firemonkey multi device project

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

In a FMX multi device project I show a form with `ShowModal()`
and on an event of that form I call another form with `ShowModal()` without closing the 1st one.
But this second form stays behind the first form.

How can I set the 2nd form to be on top of the 1st form without closing the 1st form?

I've tried to set:

```
`FormStyle` to `StayOnTop`
Call `Form1.SendToBack`
Call Form2.BringToFront
```

The only way I have managed to accomplish to show the second form is by hiding the 1st form and showing it again when second form is closed.

But if possible I like to just always show the second form on top without hiding the 1st.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Below code on how both forms are created.

**NOTE: Both form2 and form3 are transparent. Maybe this has something to do with it? I've had problems with this before.**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  form2: TForm2;
begin
  form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  form2.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if ModalResult = mrOk then
      begin
        //Some Code
      end;
    end);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  form3: TForm3;
begin
  form3 := TForm3.Create(nil); // I've tried to set the owner, this didn't help
  form3.Parent := Self;        // Here I've tried to set parent form2 and even form 1
  form3.ShowModal(          // This form is shown behind form2
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if ModalResult = mrOk then
      begin
        //Some Code
      end;
    end);
end;
```

So as you can see 2 forms are created showmodal.
Form1 is opened with Show instead of showmodal.
Form2 is created with a buttonclick event on form1 
and form3 is also created with a buttonclick event, but on form2.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I'm sorry but how does that question got anything to do with my question?

Comment: Did you try to set the `ParentForm` property?

Comment: @LURD how can I use ParentForm property? It's ready only

Comment: @TomBrunberg as i stated in my question it's a multi device project. So that means for Android and iOS

Comment: The value of ParentForm is set when you change the Parent property. `form2 := TForm2.Create(nil); form2.Parent := form1;`

Comment: @LURD I have tried that, but doesn't work. Also setting owner doesn't work either.

Comment: @Remi: What you are looking for is an FMX equivalent of the VCL's `PopupParent` property, but it doesn't exist in FMX. The `Parent` property is the way to set such relationships.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but setting the parent doesn't work. Already tried this. My 2nd form still is behind my 1st.

Comment: @Remi I don't see how the 2nd can be behind the 1st if the 1st is the Parent of the 2nd. Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the behavior?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've updated my question. Hope this is enough.

Comment: @Remi `form2 := ShowModal(...)` and `form3 := ShowModal(...)` are not valid statements, which means you did not copy/paste real code.  Presumably you meant `form2.ShowModal(...)` and `form3.ShowModal(...)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, sorry. I've edited it.